# Having some problem in displaying the output of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

can anyone tell me what is wrong with my coding and why it is not displaying the output? there is something wrong in my if statements and I cant figure out what it is I tried many things but it still now working any suggestions? it suppose to be like this same as the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vv0h.png)

```js
var Fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var Lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
var days = document.getElementById("days").value;
var request = document.getElementById("request").value;
var val = Number(document.getElementById("room").value);
var n = Number(document.getElementById("days").value);
var total = "";

function myFunction() {

  if (n <= 1) {
    n = prompt(" minimum reservation period is 2 daye try again");
  } 
  else if (val == "King $30") {
    total = n * 30;
  } 
  else if (val == "Double 20") {
    total = n * 20;
  } 
  else    (val == "Single 10") {
    total = n * 10;
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " Dear " + Fname + Lname + " , thank you for booking with us.";
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = " Expected Arrival Date: " + date;
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = " Booked: " + val + " for " + days + "days ";
  document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = " Amount:=$ " + total;
  document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = " Any Special Request: " + request;
  
};
```

```html
<h3> Hotel Registration Form </h3>
<p style="color:green">BOOK YOUR STAY WITH US...!</p>

<form>
  <label><b> GUEST:</b> </label>

  <input type="text" id="fname" size="20">
  <input type="text" id="lname" size="20">

  <br>
  <label style="margin-left:65px"> First Name </label>
  <label style="margin-left:105px"> Last Name </label>

  <br><br>

  <label><b>Arrival Date:</b></label>
  <input type="date" id="date">

  <br><br>

  <label><b>Room Type:</b></label>
  <input list="room">
  <datalist id="room">
    <option value="King $30">
    <option value="Double $20">
    <option value="Single $10">
  </datalist>

  <br><br>

  <label><b> Number of Days:</b></label>
  <input type="text" size="12" id="days">

  <br><br>

  <label><b> Any Special Request:</b></label>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="request"></textarea>

  <br>

  <button type="reset" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> CLEAR </button>
  <button type="submit" onClick="myFunction()" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> BOOK </button>
</form>

<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result1"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result2"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result3"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result4"> </p>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you specify a condition, you cannot use "else".

```
else (val == "Single 10")
```

write this instead

```
else if (val == "Single 10")
```

You will see that the problem is solved. Have a nice day.

Comment: it worked!! but now im facing another problem that the prompt keeps showing whenever I press book it suppose to show only when I write in number of days blank the value zero

Comment: Check my current answer I just edited code

Comment: you need to declare variables inside function --otherwise value of variables are always empty

Answer (score 1):

An `else` statement does not need a condition

```
else if (val == "Single 10"){
    
}
else{}
```

Check this out:

```js
function myFunction() {

  var Fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var Lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  var days = document.getElementById("days").value;
  var request = document.getElementById("request").value;
  var val = Number(document.getElementById("room").value);
  var n = Number(document.getElementById("days").value);
  var total = "";

  if (n < 3) {
    console.log(n);
    n = alert("Minimum reservation period is 2 daye try again");
  } 
  else if (val == "King $30") {
    total = n * 30;
  } 
  else if (val == "Double 20") {
    total = n * 20;
  } 
  else if (val == "Single 10") {
    total = n * 10;
  } 
  else {}

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " Dear " + Fname + Lname + " , thank you for booking with us.";
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = " Expected Arrival Date: " + date;
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = " Booked: " + val + " for " + days + "days ";
  document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = " Amount:=$ " + total;
  document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = " Any Special Request: " + request;

}
```

```html
<h3> Hotel Registration Form </h3>
<p style="color:green">BOOK YOUR STAY WITH US...!</p>

<form>
  <label><b> GUEST:</b> </label>

  <input type="text" id="fname" size="20">
  <input type="text" id="lname" size="20">

  <br>
  <label style="margin-left:65px"> First Name </label>
  <label style="margin-left:105px"> Last Name </label>

  <br><br>

  <label><b>Arrival Date:</b></label>
  <input type="date" id="date">

  <br><br>

  <label><b>Room Type:</b></label>
  <input list="room">
  <datalist id="room">
    <option value="King $30">
    <option value="Double $20">
    <option value="Single $10">
  </datalist>

  <br><br>

  <label><b> Number of Days:</b></label>
  <input type="number" id="days">

  <br><br>

  <label><b> Any Special Request:</b></label>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="request"></textarea>

  <br>

  <button type="reset" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> CLEAR </button>
  <button type="submit" onClick="myFunction()" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> BOOK </button>
</form>

<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result1"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result2"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result3"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result4"> </p>
```

Comment: i must solve the coding with java script too

Comment: You can try this code
else  if(val == "Single 10")  {

        total = n * 10;}
else{}

Comment: it worked!! but now im facing another problem that the prompt keeps showing whenever I press book it suppose to show only when I write in number of days blank the value zero

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.querySelector('button[type=submit]').addEventListener('click', function myFunction(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var Fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var Lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  var days = document.getElementById("days").value;
  var request = document.getElementById("request").value;
  var val = Number(room.value);
  var n = Number(days);

  if (n <= 1) {
    n = prompt(" minimum reservation period is 2 daye try again");
    days.value = n
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " Dear " + Fname + Lname + " , thank you for booking with us.";
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = " Expected Arrival Date: " + date;
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = " Booked: " + val + " for " + days + "days ";
  document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = " Amount:=$ " + val * n;
  document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = " Any Special Request: " + request;

});
```

```html
<h3> Hotel Registration Form </h3>
<p style="color:green">BOOK YOUR STAY WITH US...!</p>

<form>
  <label><b> GUEST:</b> </label>

  <input type="text" id="fname" size="20">
  <input type="text" id="lname" size="20">

  <br>
  <label style="margin-left:65px"> First Name </label>
  <label style="margin-left:105px"> Last Name </label>

  <br><br>

  <label><b>Arrival Date:</b></label>
  <input type="date" id="date">

  <br><br>

  <label><b>Room Type:</b></label>

  <select id="room">
    <option value=30>King $30</option>
    <option value=20>Double $20</option>
    <option value=10>Single $10</option>
  </select>

  <br><br>

  <label><b> Number of Days:</b></label>
  <input type="text" size="12" id="days">

  <br><br>

  <label><b> Any Special Request:</b></label>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="request"></textarea>

  <br>

  <button type="reset" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> CLEAR </button>
  <button type="submit" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> BOOK </button>
</form>

<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result1"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result2"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result3"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result4"> </p>
```

Comment: @bel3atar You should explain your code - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer